# How to find the inverse matrix of the form $AA^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to find the inverse matrix of the form $AA^T$.

Since $AA^T$ is invertible, we must have
\begin{align*}
A=P
\begin{bmatrix}I&O
\end{bmatrix}Q.
\end{align*}

Set
\begin{align*}
B=Q^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}I\\O
\end{bmatrix}P^{-1}
\end{align*}
and my first guess is 
$$(AA^T)^{-1}=B^TB$$
but when I come to check whether it is right, I find that some particular properties should be posed on $P$ and $Q$, thus on $A$.

I'm wondering that if there's a formula for this like the Cauchy-Binet formula
to compute the determinant of $AA^T$.

Any help or reference is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: ${A^T}^{-1}A^{-1}$ then $$AA^T{A^T}^{-1}A^{-1}=AIA^{-1}=AA^{-1}=I$$?

Comment: But $A$ might be a $m \times n$ matrix where $m<n$.